# Customizing \maketitle output with \minipage's inside \titlehead => Alignment problems

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles, koma-script, minipage, width

I am trying to customize the title of my `scrreprt` class document.

The `\titlehead` looks like this (basically, three 'columns' created with three instances of `\minipage`):

```
  \titlehead{

    \large

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{logo}
    \end{minipage}
% 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      Foo \\
      Bar \\
      Baz
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
    Fubar
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
  }
```

I have two problems:

1. I want the top of the logo, to align with the top of the text in the other two minipages. I used the `[t]` option of `\minipage` to achieve this. But while the two textual minipages line up properly, the image doesn't. It gets rendered much higher than the text. I assume this is because `\includegraphics` is *not* text and so, the `[t]` option is meaningless for the first minipage. So what should I be doing to set this right?
2. I expected the total widths of the minipages to add up to `\textwidth`. But if I set the third minipage to `0.3\textwidth` (so that the total width adds up to whole), PDFLaTeX decides to push my third minipage down because apparently the three of them side-by-side are too wide. Is there some way I can cleanly fix this? e.g. like, making the third `\minipage` *fill* the available horizontal space? If so, how?

Comment: i won't tackle the alignment, but the width problem might be solved by placing a `%` immediately after the first two instances of `\end{minipage}`.  another approach, decidedly plain, not latex, is to insert `\hss` in those same locations, setting `\parfillskip=0pt` locally, and ending the `\titlehead` argument with `\par`.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton! I had forgotten that those newlines count for white space as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\adjustbox{valign=t,left=0.3\textwidth}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.27\textwidth]{logo}}% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  Foo \\
  Bar \\
  Baz
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\raggedleft
    Fubar
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Notice how the end of lines are masked so they don't count as a space.

The `demo` option to `graphicx` and the `geometry` package are just to show the example (they provide a mock image and the frame respectively).

[image]